# Rasa integration pipeline with HuggingFace

Tags: huggingface-transformers, rasa

I'm trying to configure Rasa to use models pretrained at HuggingFace. This is my setup

```
language: fr
pipeline:
    - name: LanguageModelTokenizer
    - name: LanguageModelFeaturizer
      model_name: "bert"
      model_weights: "setu4993/LaBSE"
      cache_dir: "/rasa/model"
```

[The HuggingFace model is here](https://huggingface.co/setu4993/LaBSE)

After I run “rasa train”, it says OSError: Model name “setu4993/LaBSE” was not found. Any idea how to integrate this huggingface model to Rasa?

Can we include multiple HuggingFace pipeline in Rasa configuration? Example

```
pipeline:
    - model_name: "bert"
...
    - model_name: "xlnet"
```

Answer (score 3):

In order to use HuggingFace Transformers in your pipeline in your `config.yml` file,
you have to do the following:

1. run the following in your terminal `pip install rasa[transformers] --use-feature=2020-solver`
2. in your `config.yml` file you add the following:

   ```
   - name: HFTransformersNLP
     model_name: "bert" # Name of the language model to use
     model_weights: "rasa/LaBSE" # Pre-Trained weights to be loaded
   - name: LanguageModelTokenizer
   - name: LanguageModelFeaturizer
   ```

Comment: InvalidConfigException: Can't load class for name 'HFTransformersNLP'. Please make sure to provide a valid name or module path and to register it using the '@DefaultV1Recipe.register' decorator.